Boost.Locale in MSYS2 ucrt64 Returns "Locale Name: *"
I'm working with Boost.Locale in MSYS2's ucrt64 environment on a Windows machine.
Despite installing the entire Boost library and having locales like en_US and en_US.utf8 available, Boost.Locale consistently returns "Locale Name: *" when attempting to generate a locale.
My code compiles into a .exe file without any warnings or errors.
Code That Fails to Generate Locale
Here's a basic code snippet that should generate a valid locale, but it returns "Locale Name: *":
#include <boost/locale.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    try {
        boost::locale::generator gen;
        std::locale loc = gen("en_US.utf8");  // Or gen("en_US")
        std::cout << "Locale Name: " << loc.name() << std::endl;
    } catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << "Error creating locale: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

Relevant Portion of My Makefile
Here's the relevant part of my Makefile, including compiler settings and linking information:
# Compiler settings
CXX := g++
CPPFLAGS := -Iinclude -IC:/msys64/ucrt64/include
CXXFLAGS := -g -O0 -Wall -std=c++20 -mtune=generic -Wextra -pedantic -Wshadow -Wredundant-decls -Wsign-compare
LDFLAGS := -Llib -LC:/msys64/ucrt64/lib
LDLIBS := -lm -lboost_locale-mt -lboost_regex-mt -licudt -licuuc

Additional Context

MSYS2 Locale Check: The command locale -a shows en_US and en_US.utf8 as available locales.
System Locale: Running systeminfo | find "System Locale" in CMD shows en-us;English (United States).
Environment Variables: I set LANG and LC_ALL to en_US.utf8, but this did not resolve the issue.
Boost Installation: The entire Boost library is installed in MSYS2's ucrt64 environment, including Boost.Locale. Commands used: pacman -S mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-icu,  pacman -S mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-boost.

What I've Tried

Tried generating different locales, including C, en_US.UTF-8, en_US, and en-us.
Tried compiling and running the project in both MSYS2 UCRT64 Shell and a regular CMD.
Checked for errors or exceptions, none are thrown, but the output remains "Locale Name: *".


Does this answer your question? Using boost locale generator correctly

If you bother to eyeball the source code like https://github.com/boostorg/locale/blob/develop/include/boost/locale/localization_backend.hpp then you notice comments talking about "en_US.UTF-8" not "en_US.utf8".  Every character mattes.

@ÖöTiib If I use "en_US.UTF-8", I still get "Locale Name: *".

Happens on Linux too. However, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale/name has this little snippet: 'If the locale is not a copy of a system-supplied locale, the string "*" is returned.' -- and since boost is supplying the stuff, not "the system", maybe that's the reason... Does your locale work as expected?

@ChristianStieber you are correct, i was able to use locales i don't have installed and they functionally worked. i tested it by doing to lower case with locale on "ISTANBUL", with en_US.UTF-8 the output is "Istanbul", but with tr_TR.UTF-8 the output is "ıstanbul"

I made this a new question and answered it:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78377690/how-to-verify-boostlocalegenerator-in-c
