How to Verify boost::locale::generator in C++?
How do I verify boost::locale::generator in C++? I have the following code, but it always returns "Locale Name: *".
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/locale.hpp>

int main() {
    try {
        boost::locale::generator gen;
        std::locale loc = gen("en_US.UTF-8");
        std::cout << "Locale Name: " << loc.name() << std::endl;
    } catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << "Error creating locale: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}

From the documentation: cppreference.com, it states that "If the locale is not a copy of a system-supplied locale, the string '*' is returned." Since Boost is supplying the locale, we cannot use locale.name() to verify that the locale was properly created.
Given this limitation, how can I verify if boost::locale::generator is working properly?

Helping making the point clearer: these all return "*" even when the locales are installed. No error is raised even for "nOnSeNsE" locale names: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d37cd91575c7c762

@sehe I believe the reason is that Boost always provides the locale. I have "en_US.UTF-8" installed, and it returns "". I don't have "tr_TR.UTF-8" installed, and it also returns "". From a functionality perspective, they both works.

I'd be surprised, because a good number of issues and even code comments deal with "fallback to system locale" [when] "a locale doesn't exist on the system". (Also, Boost are essentially C++ libraries, not Locale maintainers)

@sehe That's odd. I tested it also on Ubuntu and when I ran locale -a, I got a limited list with "C", "POSIX", and a few versions of English, but no Turkish. I have the latest version of Ubuntu and installed libraries using:
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
sudo apt-get install libicu-dev
I also use C++ 20.

Oh. ICU might explain things. A lot. Because they're NOT essentially C++ libraries, instead they're essentially locale implementers.

@sehe Hmm, so is ICU supplying the locale for me? But even without ICU, name() still returns '*', right?

To verify boost::locale::generator, we can check its functionality by using a simple example that converts text to lowercase in different locales.
Here's a code snippet that demonstrates how to do this:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/locale.hpp>

std::string to_lower(const std::string& text, const std::string& locale_name) {
    boost::locale::generator gen;
    std::locale loc = gen(locale_name);
    return boost::locale::to_lower(text, loc);
}

void print_hex(const std::string& text) {
    for (char c : text) {
        std::cout << std::hex << static_cast<int>(static_cast<unsigned char>(c)) << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    // Uppercase text that we'll convert to lowercase
    std::string english_text = "ISTANBUL";

    // Convert to lowercase with the English locale
    std::string english_lower = to_lower(english_text, "en_US.UTF-8");
    std::cout << "English Lowercase: " << english_lower << std::endl;
    print_hex(english_lower);

    // Convert to lowercase with the Turkish locale
    std::string turkish_lower = to_lower(english_text, "tr_TR.UTF-8");
    std::cout << "Turkish Lowercase: " << turkish_lower << std::endl;
    print_hex(turkish_lower);

    return 0;
}

Output:
English Lowercase: istanbul
69 73 74 61 6e 62 75 6c

Turkish Lowercase: ıstanbul
c4 b1 73 74 61 6e 62 75 6c

By converting the text to lowercase in different locales, we can see that the results differ. This indicates that boost::locale::generator is working as expected because it properly handles locale-specific transformations.

This only works for specific known locale facets. While the code works, this strikes me as an AI-assisted answer, because it misses the question?

Hah. I didn't notice it was a self-answer. That's ... surprising because nothing in your question suggests that being able to detect Turkish collation would help you. In fact, it doesn't help at all for the question code.

@sehe The problem is that there's no clear way to validate the locale because it returns "*" for every locale boost generated. After I got "ıstanbul" as a result, I knew that "tr_TR.UTF-8" worked.
It only tests for Turkish, and such a test should be done for the specific locale you want to validate.
If you know a better way to validate that a locale works, I'd be glad to hear it and edit my answer accordingly. Alternatively, you can respond separately.

I don't. I spent some (considerable) time. My best bet would be to use POSIX/Win32 specific APIs to check beforehand. It would seem like a pretty essential feature for Boost Locale to add though. They added /some/ checks in the past: https://github.com/boostorg/locale/pull/177/commits/42c2a6d6e07637bc29130147b740b2ed96ddc275
